# onResume() method is not calling from the same activity

Tags: android

I am running an Activity using service in my Application. So if the service is running and keyguard is locked, i am unlocking it through code and showing again my activity. For that, i wrote the code in the onReceive() method of the Activity.

```
protected void onResume() 
{
    Log.d("Testing","ONRESUME OF HOME SCREEN");
    // only when screen turns on
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onResume();
 }
```

But when i am moving from my activity to another activity(Suppose phone's Home Screen),and locking the key guard, it is unlocking  and showing my activity. But if my activity is showing and locking the key guard, it is unable to unlock the key guard, unless i am manually unlocking it.

I am not getting whats the problem. Please help....

Comment: Problem is not clear by the description given, so please elaborate what do you want to do.

Comment: Suppose one activity i am showing for a particular time period using service. That activity consists one image and one digital clock. Now assume that my activity is showing in the phones home screen, i mean it is running and i locked the screen. So i want to unlock it automatically and again it should show my activity. For that i wrote the above code.

Comment: what do you mean by "onReceive() method of the Activity." do you know what is activity? activity does not have onReceive() method.

Comment: Oh Sorry..Its OnResume() method..Sorry again

Comment: I wrote the code inside the onResume() method. I already mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

onResume is called when your activity has control on event thread.

And if you have locked the screen(means start other activity on this activity), onResume wont be called, because event on activity will be fired would be: onPause(), onStop() after that when you finish other activity on top of this activity(screen), then onResume(), and onStart() would be invoked.

If your lock screen is a view component to be shown in the same activity, then neither of activity lifecycle method will be invoked.

Comment: But when i am moving to another activity(Suppose phones home Screen) and then locking the phone, it is unlocking and showing my Activity only. That time it is going inside the OnResume() method. It is printing the Log.

Comment: because you are displaying your activity on time and when you start an activity then following step of actions followed-> startactivity-> onCreate()-> onStart()-> onResume()

Comment: Create LockScreen other activity independent of your activity.

Comment: I did not get your point. So in that LockScreen what should i mention??

Comment: in Lock screen just image and code of lock and finishing activity